# how to optimize an HQL query that join two big tables

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

i have a HQL query like this one :

```
Select foo
From Foo foo, Bar bar
Where foo.number = bar.number
```

but it takes hibernate 4, 5 seconds to execute because the two tables are very big ones.
and i did a tracing with Hibernate stat and trace log and found that this HQL query execute 500 Select! that why it takes lot of time because i have 3 manyToOne in the first table and 7 ManyToOne & OneToMany in the other one.
is there a way to optimize this HQL query without using or converting it to SQL query?

in case of using native SQL query, i need to remap the results from objects to a foo entity object witch i don't prefer.

Comment: How many rows are you retrieving? Are you applying any filtering condition? Otherwise I'll be slow.

Comment: You are fetching all the data from your two BIG tables (possibly more data because of possible additional relationships). Definitely it will be slow.

Comment: yes, i did a tracing with Hibernate stat and trace log and found that this HQL query executes 500 Select! that why it takes a lot of time because i have 3 manyToOne in the first table and 7 ManyToOne & OneToMany in the other one.
do you know how to do all this select in a single one? or any other solution that makes the HQL execute in a reasonable time less than 1 sec? i did try adding an Inner Fetch Join to get a single parent object and child and not all the child object but it still executes the 500 Select!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following annotations:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "your_mapping_name")
        @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
            @BatchSize(size = 10)
```

for more info you can review: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Without the entities code is harder to find the exactly answer for that, but most of the times the problem is the **EAGER** relationships.

> i have 3 manyToOne in the first table and 7 ManyToOne & OneToMany in the other one.

The first step is be sure that all `ToOne` mappings are `LAZY` and not `EAGER`. Every `ToOne` (`@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne`) relationship is `EAGER` **by default**. So, change the relationship to `LAZY`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Or:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Be also sure if the `ToMany` relationships are **not** `EAGER` (they are `LAZY` by default).